# How do I destroy a ship realm in the Archimedes' Ships mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I installed the **Archimedes' Ships** mod and created a ship realm using the craft table and now I can't destroy the ship.

I tried to burn it, break it, even poured lava on it but it still doesn't get destroyed. Can someone please tell me how I can get rid of the ship?

Comment: Cant destroy what,exactly?

Comment: Do you have a link to a mod wiki?  I know nothing about this mod, so a little more information would be helpful.

Comment: Try to ask directly to the official thread for Archimedes mod, If we don't have any link to the wiki or something else, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Move the ship close to the shore and then press "K". Click "Align" and then click "Disassemble". The ship will turn back into Minecraft blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try /asdestroy whilst standing close to the ship. /asdestroy destroys every ship within 16 blocks but you can change the range if you want